Page jumps to top position of div in Chrome by clicking on label
I have a vertical fullscreen slider. Everything works in Safari, but in Chrome the page jumps to the top position of the slide. The radio buttons are at the top of the DIV "css-slider-wrapper" and I navigate by clicking on the label related to the radio button. The reason that the page jumps to the top position of the slide is, that the radio buttons are at the top of the DIV "css-slider-wrapper".
I already tried to place the radio buttons in a wrapper with a position absolute bottom 0, but then the slider doesn't work anymore. Also when I place the radio buttons in the DIV "slider-pagination" the slider doesn't work anymore.
How can I prevent, that by clicking on a label the page jumps to the position of the radio buttons in Chrome?
This is the original slider:
https://www.htmllion.com/examples/pure-css-based-fullscreen-slider-demo.html
The problem is: I use is inside a page. Only 1 section of the page is a slider.


.css-slider-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
    
.slider, .slider2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}   
    
.slide1, .slide4 {
  background: #feffca;
  left: 0;
}

.slide2, .slide5 {
  background: #feffca;
  left: 100%
}

.slide3, .slide6 {
  background: #feffca;
  left: 200%
}
    
.slide4, .slide5, .slide6{
  background: #c7eefb;
}
  
.slider > div, .slider2 > div {
  text-align: center;
}
   
.slider-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slider-pagination label {
  font-family: 'ABC Simon Mono Thin';   
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}
    
.slider-pagination .page1, .slider-pagination .page4{
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
    
/* Slider slide effect */
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider, .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider, .slide-radio5:checked ~ .slider2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider, .slide-radio6:checked ~ .slider2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" checked id="slider_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">

  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1">Navigation 1</label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2">Navigation 2</label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="page3">Navigation 3</label>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slide1">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      Text
    </div>
  </div>      
  <div class="slider slide2">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    Text
  </div>      
  <div class="slider slide3">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      Text
    </div>
  </div>




Have you tried putting the radio buttons into each corresponding slider?

Yes, but then the slider doesn't slide anymore. And the navigation disappears.

I dont understand the problem based on your explanation + the provided code :D

Well obviously you will have to adjust the CSS accordingly as well, which should be easy for you if you've done the slider yourself.

I've adjusted the slider. The original slider I've found on the internet.

The problem is that the page jumps to the top of the div when I click on the navigation. Therefore the slide is at the top of the browser window. When the slider is at the middle of the page it's irritating, because you have to scroll down again to the position you where before.

Will it be possible to place the radio buttons at the bottom of the DIV. That will solve the problem. The problem is, that when I give them a position absolute, the slider doesn't work anymore.

This is the actual slider.
https://www.htmllion.com/examples/pure-css-based-fullscreen-slider-demo.html

The page moves up, because the input's are at the top of the page, and the focus moves to them.
So, input[class^="slide-radio"] { display: none; } should solve the problem
